# Clarification about Furstenberg proof about infinity of primes

Tags: general-topology, definition

[Furstenberg's proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_Primes_is_Infinite/Proof_2) defines a topology where a set is open if it is a union of sequences

```
S(a,b), where: S(a,b)={an+b:n∈ℤ}=aℤ+b.
```

However, then it says this is equivalent to saying that a set

$U$ is open iff $\forall x \in U \space \exists a \ne 0 \space s.t. S(a,x) \subseteq U$

I am not sure how this easily follows from the defintion.

Comment: This is an if and only if statement, could you prove at least one direction, to begin? Which direction do you find difficult? If $x\in U$ then $x=an+b$ for some $a,n,b$ with $a\mathbb Z+b\subseteq U$. Notice $a\mathbb Z+b=a\mathbb Z+x$. Also, you probably do not mean $S(a,x) \in U$ but $S(a,x) \subseteq  U$.

Comment: You mean $S(a,x)\subseteq U$.

Comment: @Mirko If $\forall x \in U \exists a \space s.t. S(a,x) \subseteq U$ then  $\bigcup_{x}S(a,x) \subseteq U = \bigcup_{x} \{x\} \subseteq \bigcup_{a} S(a,x)$. Now, I missed the other part because I missed the easy observation that $x \in S(a,b)$ iff $S(a,b)=S(a,x)$

Comment: The first chapter of the book Prime Number Records lists about 23 different proofs that either there is no largest prime or that the there  exists the set of all primes and that it is not finite, including the "topological proof". My favorite is an observation by Prof. Leo Morse that it suffices to exhibit a strictly increasing sequence of pairwise disjoint  members of $\Bbb N.$ For example the Fermat numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real obstacle.

Note that we can also write $S(a,b)=\{\,t\in\Bbb Z:a\mid t-b\,\}$
Assume $U$ is open, say $U=\bigcup_{(a,b)\in I}S(a,b)$.
Then there exists $(a,b)\in I$ such that $x\in S(a,b)$ and of course $S(a,b)\subseteq U$. Now observe that $S(a,b)=S(a,x)$ if $x=\in S(a,b)$: We have $x=ma+b$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$ and then $$t\in S(a,b)\iff a\mid t-b\iff a\mid t-x\iff t\in S(a,x).$$

On the other hand, assume that $U$ is a set such that for each $x\in U$, there exists $a=a(x)$ such that $S(a(x),x)\subseteq U$. Then clearly, $U=\bigcup_{(a,b)\in I}S(a,b)$, where $I=\{\,(a(x),x): x\in U\,\}$.

Comment: I had missed the easy observation that $x \in S(a,b)$ iff $S(a,b)=S(a,x)$

Answer (score 0):

Both just say that the set $\{S(a,b): a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, a \neq 0 \}$ forms a base for the topology in question.

And this collection fulfills the two conditions to be a base for a topology: the union of all $S(a,b)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ (even $S(1,1) = \mathbb{Z}$ and for $n \in S(a,b) \cap S(c,d)$ we can find $S(a',b') $ such that $n \in S(a', b') \subseteq S(a,b) \cap S(c,d)$ (check this).

Defining such a collection and defining it as a base is quite usual practice.